# How to set the text block at middle between of 2 column in grid with list box

Tags: wpf

Hi guys I would like to ask how to make the text block at middle between of 2 column in grid ?

Thanks.

[Downlaod Project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=233E2A690341BB1D!597&authkey=!AFLRy3gQrUzwHs4&ithint=file%2Czip)
[image]

Comment: Will the Grid adjusts when its edge is aligned with its container, like a window? Part of your 'AAA' may not be visible if it is on the leftmost of a Window's client area.

Answer (score 0):

You could use columnspan to insert your usercontrol in two or more columns:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="Foobar" Grid.Column="1" 
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: This only applies if the columns are of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2">Hello i am Here</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

You can remove `Height` and `VerticalAlignment` attribute if want to fill the window